# Give me some hints to prove this

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct odd primes. Show that

$\sum_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \lfloor \frac{qj}{p} \rfloor +\sum_{j=1}^{\frac{q-1}{2}} \lfloor \frac{pj}{q} \rfloor = \frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{4}$

Comment: You did not suggest an equality. Can you please complete the question?

Comment: Or more generally, the thing to be proven or shown should be a true/false statement, e.g. the sum is equal to 2, the sum is positive, the sum is not divisible by 3, the sum is prime, the sum is over 9000...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A geometric hint is that, consider a line segment $L:y = \frac pq x$ between the origin and $(q,p)$. The following image shows an example where $p=7$ and $q=19$:

[image: Example for p=7, q=19]

The first summation $\sum_{y=1}^{\frac{p-1}2}\left\lfloor\frac qpy\right\rfloor$ would correspond to some kind of area to the left of line $L$, explicitly the region:

$$0 \le y \le \frac {p+1}2,\quad 0 \le x \le \left\lfloor\frac qp\lfloor y\rfloor\right\rfloor$$

(Shown as a dark green region to the left of the dashed line and inside the blue rectangle)

The second summation $\sum_{x=1}^{\frac{q-1}2}\left\lfloor\frac pqx\right\rfloor$ would correspond to some kind of area below of line $L$, explicitly the region:

$$0 \le x \le \frac {q+1}2,\quad 0 \le y \le \left\lfloor\frac pq\lfloor x\rfloor\right\rfloor$$

(Shown as a light red region below the dashed line and inside the blue rectangle)

Separating the two regions is a path of neighbouring integer cells between the origin $(0,0)$ and the point $(\frac{q+1}2,\frac{p+1}2)$. (Shown as white cells around the dashed line and inside the blue rectangle)

By counting the number of horizontal and vertical grid lines the line $L$ crosses, the path contains $\frac{p-1}2 + \frac{q-1}2 + 1$ squares. The condition that $p$ and $q$ are coprime is important here, that $L$ does not pass through any integer lattice point between the origin and $(q,p)$.

Counting the three kinds of cells that together form the rectangle between the origin and $(\frac{q+1}2, \frac{p+1}2)$,

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{y=1}^{\frac{p-1}2}\left\lfloor\frac qp y\right\rfloor + 
\sum_{x=1}^{\frac{q-1}2}\left\lfloor\frac pq x\right\rfloor + \left(\frac{p-1}2 + \frac{q-1}2 + 1\right)
&= \frac{p+1}2\cdot \frac{q+1}2\\
&= \left(\frac{p-1}2+1\right)\left(\frac{q-1}2+1\right)\\
\sum_{y=1}^{\frac{p-1}2}\left\lfloor\frac qp y\right\rfloor + 
\sum_{x=1}^{\frac{q-1}2}\left\lfloor\frac pq x\right\rfloor &= \frac{p-1}2\cdot \frac{q-1}2
\end{align*}$$